# Google Script gets stuck in a loop when trying to connect to Excel

Tags: excel, loops, google-apps-script, web-applications, append

doPost() function gets stuck in a loop printing "1st break". All access permissions have been given.

```
function sendText(id,text){
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}






function doPost(e){
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;

sendText(id, "1st break");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(test123);
  sheet.appendRow(["success!"]);
  // var liftingGears = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("test");

sendText(id, "2nd break");
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. doPost should have a `return` See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: telegramUrl, ssid and text123 undefined